# WinDBG conditional breakpoints on member of a class pointer value

Tags: windbg

Trying to set breakpoint to class member, but I get syntax error or error saying "could not resolve".

Target variable is abc of class pointer xyz.

```
0:000> ??@@c++(xyz->abc)
short 0n812

0:000> dt xyz
Local var @ rbx Type Prop*
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x00007ffd`b9229510 
   +0x058 abc          : 0n0147
```

Attempts:

```
0:000> bu ***!***::function+0x56 ".if (@@c++(xyz->abc))==147) {.echo 'hit'} .else {gc}"

^ Syntax error in '.if ....'
```

I want to set breakpoint when pProp->ydu value is equal to 147.

Comment: you are missing a bracket it appears is it a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

source

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    Rectangle (int x ,int y) : width(x) , height(y) {} 
    int area (void) {return (width*height);}
};
void CalcArea(int i,int j,Rectangle *rect) {
    cout << "Area for Rect("<<i<<","<<j<<") = "<<rect->area()<< endl;
}       
int main () {
    int i,j; 
    for(i=10,j=10; (i<100 && j<100); i+=5,j+=10){
        Rectangle rect (i,j);
        CalcArea(i,j,&rect);        
    }
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with vs 2017 community cmd prompt

```
cl /EHsc /W4 /analyze /Zi /Od classy.cpp /link /release
```

executed

```
classy.exe
Area for Rect(10,10) = 100
Area for Rect(15,20) = 300
Area for Rect(20,30) = 600
Area for Rect(25,40) = 1000
Area for Rect(30,50) = 1500
Area for Rect(35,60) = 2100
Area for Rect(40,70) = 2800
Area for Rect(45,80) = 3600
Area for Rect(50,90) = 4500
```

loaded in windbg and set a conditional break point and run

```
:\>cdb classy.exe
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86

0:000> bu classy!CalcArea ".if(((@@c++(rect->width))==0n40)){ .echo \"hit\" } .else{gc}"

0:000> bl
 0 e 00841100     0001 (0001)  0:**** 
classy!CalcArea ".if(  ((@@c++(rect->width))==0n40)  ) { .echo \"hit\" } .else {gc}"

0:000> g

Area for Rect(10,10) = 100
Area for Rect(15,20) = 300
Area for Rect(20,30) = 600
Area for Rect(25,40) = 1000
Area for Rect(30,50) = 1500
Area for Rect(35,60) = 2100
hit <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
eax=00000028 ebx=7ffdf000 ecx=002dff08 edx=00000046 esi=008c9bf0 edi=000d8b28
eip=00841100 esp=002dfef8 ebp=002dff18 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000287
classy!CalcArea:
00841100 55              push    ebp


0:000> ?? rect
class Rectangle * 0x002dff08
   +0x000 width            : 0n40  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   +0x004 height           : 0n70
0:000>
```